# Apache httpd throws intermittent 401 errors for same requests which pass otherwise

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We are using Apache httpd 2.4.7 as Dispatcher in our Production Environment. The entire setup works fine, except for that the Dispatcher throws intermittent 401 errors sometimes. For the same kind of requests (URI/Headers etc), httpd will pass 99% of the requests, but will throw 401 error on 1% of the requests. I enabled trace logs trying to debug this, but could not get any clues from it.
Can someone help on what might be the reason for such intermittent issue with httpd 2.4.7 , and any workaround to fix the same.

Comment: This should probably be on ServerFault, and not StackOverflow; but is there an `.htaccess` somewhere that is requiring authentication for some locations?

Comment: Thanks @wmorrell, but we do not have such a htaccess file. Also note that this is very intermittent and the same request works with some retries in place from the client itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check if mod evasive is enabled. I had a similar problem and it turned out to be mod evasive:

```
a2query -m evasive
```

If it is enabled, disable and reload apache2:

```
a2dismod evasive
systemctl reload apache2
```